# ZENDESK API Clients vs HTTP Requests/Responses

Tags: node.js, zendesk

I'm working on a new web application in Node JS that needs to access Zendesk to check if there are tickets created for a specific user/requester e-mail (not agent e-mail).

I came accross two scenarios where I could use to make this request. The first one is recommended by Zendesk, which is access Zendesk using one of two API Clients available for Node JS. They are **node-zendesk** by Farrin Reid and **Zendesk NodeJS API** written by Adam Gray. [Check it out here](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/api-clients/nodejs/)

Another way is to make simple HTTP Request/Responses as usual in Node, which in my case fits better for what I need. I just need to retrieve only that information and don't want more dependencies in my app for things I woudn't need.

The problem is that I am getting the message "Couldn't authenticate you" from Zendesk when I do the fetch. Maybe someone already came accross this problem and could help me out clarifying where exactly is my mistake or what I'm missing in the code.

I would appreciate a light on that.

Here is my code:

```
   async function getZendeskTickets(clientEmail) {

    const zendeskAgent = 'agent@email.com'
    const api_token = 'some token'
    const query = `type:ticket requester:${clientEmail}`;
    const url = `https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?query=${query}`

    try {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: Buffer.from(`${zendeskAgent}/token:${api_token}`).toString('base64'),
            }
        })
        let data = await res.json();
        console.log('response', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('zendesk response error', error)
    }

    return
}
```

export default getZendeskTickets;

Comment: have you tried dropping `/token` from the Authorization header? so its just `${zendeskagent}:${apikey}`?

Comment: Hi @richardsefton, that's the way Zendesk works regarding Authorization. Anyway, I've tried it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing the problem.

According to the Zendesk Docs, the Authorization in the header must be base64 enconded. I was doing in the wrong way. Also. it must heve the word "Basic" before the credential.

While the encode can be done using buffer, I just access the site https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode the credential zendeskAgent/token:api_token. The final code would be like:

```
    const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Basic YWdlbnRAZW1haWwuY29tOnNvbWUgdG9rZW4='
```

}
})